# Outlook addin in C#: what happens between Forward and Open events?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

1. In Outlook addin I have two event handlers registered, for `MailItem.Forward` and `MailItem.Open`
2. When I receive **Forward**, I am getting an object parameter that references a new `MailItem` object created for the new message.
3. When I look at `object.HTMLBody` (*or Body*), this references the same object as the original mail item does (*before forwarding*). This object contains an unmodified value of the original message.
4. When I receive **Open** event (*regarding the same object that the Forward event previously*), the event references the same object as forward, but it already contains a new `HTMLBody` (*and Body*) - it includes the forward heading etc. added to the original message.

**The problem:**

If I try to set **a new HTMLBody** object in step 3) (*in Forward event handler*), it has no effect.

After returning from event handler what I get in 4) (*in Open event handler*), is a transformed original message, before my substitution of `HTMLBody`.

So, there is something happening between Forward and Open events, that replaces the `HTMLBody` of the new object, but based on its old value (*or value of original message*).

What is that that is happening?

How can I replace the `HTMLBody` of forwarded message, not affecting the body of original message, but before it gets transformed according to the forwarding process?

Comment: I fixed my problem by adding a hidden comment tags into HTML, for example: `<!--MyTagBegin:OriginalTextHere-->ModifiedTextHere<!--MyTagEnd-->` Then, in open event (only after forward/reply occured before) I parse back the mail bringing the original content in. I don't like this solution, but unless someone helps me with my questions, I have to live with it.

Comment: Good solution. You can even answer your own question here on stackoverflow. Give it a try.

Comment: Hello, providing some example code might really help for the greater community to provide you with a much better solution than you currently have.